# How to apply Monit on a nginx PHP script

Tags: php, daemon, monit

I am using a linux tool called Monit that I am trying to monitor a PHP daemon script.

I do not know how to issue the command correctly.

Please provide me with some sample command for those who are experienced with monit.

I use command like these.

$admin: sudo monit script.php

$admin: sudo monit ./script.php

but it keep saying its not a service

Please help me on this.  I normally would run the PHP daemon like this with the command

$admin: sudo ./script.php

and it would run.  Now I want to use monit to monitor it. but my command I use above does not work.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the system is not able to locate the monit service. Do a `whereis monit` or a `locate monit` first in order to find its location. If monit has been recently installed in your system, you might need to do an `updatedb` in order for `locate` command to find it.

Once the location is found, change to that directory then try doing a `sudo monit full/path/to/script.php`

Comment: I get this notice after issuing the command.. monit: The control file '/etc/monit/monitrc' must be owned by you.

Comment: then i get this as well   monit: invalid argument -- ./daemon1.php  (-h will show valid arguments)

Comment: Looks like your apache user does not have access to the resource file for monit. You might need to change the owner/group for monitrc so that apache user can execute it

Comment: could you paste your monit config files (usually stored in /etc/monit.d)